# interval in the coefficient equation in Fourier Series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have some questions regarding the formula for the coefficient in a fourier series:

I saw a formula like this:

$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n = 1}^{n = \infty}a_n cos (\frac{n\pi x}{L}) + \sum_{n = 1 }^{n = \infty}b_n sin(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$ where L is defined as the Period of the periodic function f(x).

Then they say we can find the coefficient $a_n$ and $b_n$ using the formula:

$a_n = \frac{2}{L} \int_{0}^{L}f(x)cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})dx $  ----- (1)

But I was also given the $a_n $ can be calculated as $a_n = \frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})dx$     ------ (2)
or $a_n = \frac{2}{L}\int_{\frac{-L}{2}}^{\frac{L}{2}} cos(\frac{2\pi n x}{L})f(x)dx$ ---- (3)

I am just wondering for changing from (2) to (3), is it true that I can use a change of variable, so say let $u = 2x$ and then I think I will be able to get formula (3) from (2)?, but how about the f(x) inside the integral, do I need to change it to be in terms of f(u)? I am kind of confused.

Also how do we show (1) and (2) are the same? I think if we assume $f(x)cos(\frac{n\pi x}{L})$ is an even function, then (1) and (2) are the same. But I think f(x) is not assumed to be even. So is (1) and (2) both exact same formula for calculating $a_n$?

Comment: In your first formula the period $T = 2L$. In your first $a_n$ formula $T = 2L$ also and this formula applies if $f$ is an even function only. In your second $a_n$ formula $T = 2L$. In your third $a_n$ formula $L$ should be $T$

Comment: @Paul Hi, so T means the period? so it means L is only half of the period?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Except in your last formula L means T, not $\frac{T}{2}$.